# R boxplot with multiple categories

Tags: r

So I have a dataset that looks like this

```
Lot.Area  Neighborhood
3901      NridgHt
8400      Nonemes
7200      CollgCr
7017      SawyerW
15259     NridgHt
4280      Sawyer
20064     ClearCr
```

I want to create a scatter plot out of this data so that the neighborhood names are across the bottom and the lot.areas are on the y-axis.

I've tried doing `plot(dataSet)`, and that gets me close, but it gives me multiple values across the bottom like in this picture -

[image]

I want something similar to the above, but I want there to be only 7 buckets across the bottom, as opposed to the large number that is there right now.

How do I do that?

So I attempted Julian Urbano's answer and I got this

[image]

Why are there so many different x-values? How do know what dot corresponds to what neighborhood?

Comment: What do you mean 7 buckets? You're gonna have as many boxes as neighborhoods in your data. BTW, that image can't be created with `plot` as you mention, but with `boxplot`

Comment: How many neighbourhood's are there in your dataset - if there are more than seven what characteristics do you want to use to group/reduce them into seven groups? Are there multiple values per neighbourhood so that you can plot boxplots (as above)?

Comment: yeah there are I guess? I thought I was forcing teh boxplot onto two columns with this though -boxplot(ames.data[,c('Lot.Area')] ~ as.factor(ames.data[,c('Neighborhood')]))

Comment: I want a neighborhoods across the bottom, with Lot Area on the y-axis, I want a dot for each Lot Area in a neighborhood

Comment: `plot(as.integer(dataset$Neighborhood),dataset$Lot.Area)`

Comment: the problem with that is the neighborhood names don't appear along hte bottom, integers do

Comment: You have that many values in the x-axis because you have that many different neighborhoods. If you do `table(dataset$Neighborhood)` you'll see how many different neighborhoods you have, and how many data points for each of them. You only see seven names because the rest don't fit in the space you have. Make the plot bigger or plot names vertically

Comment: ohhhhh god that's really stupid of me - so right now it's setting a default - is there a way to specify that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
plot(as.integer(t$Neighborhood),t$Lot.Area, axes=F, ylab="Lot Area", xlab="")
axis(1, labels=unique(t$Neighborhood),
     at=as.integer(unique(t$Neighborhood)), las=2)
axis(2)
box()
```

[image]

Comment: hey Julian, thanks for the help, almost there - please check the question

Answer (score 0):

Well with one value for each neighborhood, it won't look very nice.

Here's an example of a `boxplot` with an R data set.

```
boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris, ylab = "Sepal.Width")
```

[image]

And here's a `stripchart` with your data.

```
stripchart(Lot.Area~Neighborhood, data = dat, vertical = TRUE)
```

[image]